# ee.Image from ee.Geometry.Point.coordiantes

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
ee.Image([1,2])
```

evaluates to two band constants image.

```
var myPoint = ee.Geometry.Point([13.683294059500382, 51.438313436248876]);
var coords = myPoint.coordinates()
```

evaluates to list of coordinates JSON
but

```
var constImage = ee.Image(coords)

print(constImage)
```

evaluates to list and not to two band image. Why? How can I create a constant multiband image from a `ee.Geometry.coordinates()` call?

EDIT: the background is that I want to calculate an image of euclidian direction from a defined point. My solution is to get x y images using `ee.Image.pixelCoordinates` and apply something like `Math.atan(x-cx, y-cy)`, where cx and cy are the coordinate of `myPoint`. Thus, I need a constant images of cx and cy. The rest is then just band math and dealing with projections. I could just copy paste the coordinates, e.g. `ee.Image(cx).addBands(ee.Image(cy))`, but the goal is to create an app in which the center point is defined by a click. So I want to be able to create an `ee.Image` from `myPoint.coordinates`.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([13.683294059500382, 51.438313436248876])
var proj = 'EPSG:32633'
var geometry = geometry.transform(proj)

//var constImage = ee.Image(geometry.coordinates())

var centerImage = ee.Image(408482.29).addBands(ee.Image(5699391.17)).rename('cx', 'cy')

var latlonImage = ee.Image.pixelCoordinates(proj)
var diffImage = latlonImage.subtract(centerImage)
var theta = diffImage.select('y').atan2(diffImage.select('x')).multiply(180).divide(3.14)
Map.addLayer(theta)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please provide a little more context information on the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it doesn't work, but this works:

```
var myPoint = ee.Geometry.Point([13.683294059500382, 51.438313436248876]);
var coords = myPoint.coordinates()

var constImage = ee.Image.constant(coords)

print(constImage)
```